# Firebase: Does changing provider Facebook account affect existing users that registered using Facebook?

Tags: firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have setup Firebase Auth using Facebook as an authentication provider.

The provider Facebook dev account was setup temporarily until a proper one was created. Now if we change the provider Facebook account, will it affect the currrent users registered using Facebook?

Will they continue to use their existing Firebase accounts or or will new accounts be created?

How does Firebase handle this case?

Example:
Andrew registered onto our app using Facebook.
Now Andrew is on level 2 based on his Firebase account.
Now we have changed the Facebook developer account associated with Firebase. Andrew is still using his old Facebook account to login, will Andrew loose his progress or not?

Comment: Will affect in terms of what? I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: I mean will Firebase generate new accounts for those users? or will they continue using the existing Firebase accounts? Because now they have other data associated with those Firebase accounts which will be lost if new Firebase accounts are created.

Comment: You can [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) their accounts, right?

Comment: It's not with different providers, it's only Facebook. What I'm asking is, if we change the Facebook developer account registered with Firebase, will that result in new Firebase accounts being created when previous users return to the app using Facebook?

Comment: Sorry for my poor wording, added an example, maybe that helps.